# How to replace default alert box with customize alert box

Tags: javascript, alert

I tried to make one exam using html forms which would find the incorrect answer and will write   the correct answer using alert box. But i want to use another customize alert box.

When i click the submit button i want to open customized alert box.

Using this alert box http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

**Thank you !!!
Thank you !!!**

---

This is the code.

```
<SCRIPT Language ="JavaScript">

function ValidateForm(){
result = new Array();
count = 0;

if (!document.forms[0].one[1].checked == true) {
result[count] = "Question 1.  Correct answer is " + document.forms[0].one[1].value + ".";
count++;
}

if (!document.forms[0].two[1].checked == true) {
result[count] = "Question 2. correct answer is" + document.forms[0].two[1].value + ".";
count++;
}

if (!document.forms[0].three[0].checked == true) {
result[count] = "Question 3. The correct answer is " + document.forms[0].three[0].value + ".";
count++;
}

if (!document.forms[0].four[2].checked == true) {
result[count] = "Question 4. The correct answer is " + document.forms[0].four[2].value + ".";
count++;
}

if (result.length > 0) {
var vString = "";
for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
vString = vString + result[i] + "\n";
}

alert(result.length + " incorrect answer:\n" + vString);
return(false);
}

else {
alert("All of the questions were answered correctly so submit email notice.");
return(true);
}
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: is there a question here that i can't see?

Comment: yes it is: When i click submit button i want to open customized alert box... replacing browser default alert box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have included [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) and the alerts plugin (js and css) you downloaded from the site you linked to...

replace 
`alert('etc etc')`

with 
`jAlert('your message here')`